# gridvies is only scrollable inside a column

Tags: flutter, dart, gridview

I am trying to use gridview inside the column widget but when i scroll up or down it just scrolls the grid view not the whole screen.

I searched for solutions and tried but no solution worked in the my case.

```
[

 Expanded(
                child: GridView.count(
                  crossAxisCount: 2,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  children: List.generate(10, (index) {
                    return Card(
                      child: Text("hello world"),
                    );
                  }),
                ),
              ),
]
```

[image]

Comment: Because `Expanded` takes available space from column and set on Expanded

Comment: what is the solution to it ??

Comment: `CustomScrollView` will better instead of draggable widget. try to run below answer

Comment: I will have to change my whole code. but is there any answer will work with my code.

Comment: Hope so, but will get the bad(worst) performance , you dont have to change that much, just use `SliverToBoxAdapter` when you need to use general widget. First split your current page into different widget and method, it will be easy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this answer ( A friend of mine gave me ). I wrapped the whole page into the singleChildScrollView()
and gave physics: NeverScrollPhysics(). and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `CustomScrollView`

```dart
return Scaffold(
  body: CustomScrollView(
    slivers: [
      SliverAppBar(),
      SliverToBoxAdapter(
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 200,
          child: ListView.builder(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
              width: 200,
              color: index.isEven ? Colors.purple : Colors.red,
              child: Text("$index"),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      SliverAlignedGrid.count(
        itemCount: 44,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => Card(child: Text("card $index")),
        crossAxisCount: 2,
      )
    ],
  ),
);
}
```

More about [CustomScrollView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomScrollView-class.html)

Comment: I have used the customScrollView but i want to fetch data from the api and view into this grid. HOw can i do this in future builder ??

Comment: You can wrap CustomScrollVIew with FutureBuilder, then use SliverGrid,